# max memory per query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How can I configure the maximum memory that a query (select query) can use in sql server 2008?

I know there is a way to set the minimum value but how about the max value? I would like to use this because I have many processes in parallel. I know about the MAXDOP option but this is for processors.

Update:

What I am actually trying to do is run some data load continuously. This data load is in the ETL form (extract transform and load).  While the data is loaded I want to run some queries ( select ). All of them are expensive queries ( containing group by ). **The most important process for me is the data load**. I obtained an average speed of 10000 rows/sec and when I run the queries in parallel it drops to 4000 rows/sec and even lower. I know that a little more details should be provided but this is a more complex product that I work at and I cannot detail it more.  Another thing that I can guarantee is that my load speed does not drop due to lock problems because I monitored and removed them.

Comment: What edition of SQL Server 2008 are you on?

Comment: The short answer is : you probably shouldn't (and if you are atempting to, then you are probably doing some thing fundamentally wrong). If you have constructed a query that you require the results from, it takes whatever it takes.

Comment: Perhaps you should describe the actual problem you are facing...

Comment: Are you talking about memory grants for sorts, hash operations etc? If so why? Are you getting semaphore waits?

Comment: I updated my question. Please review the update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any way of setting a maximum memory at a per query level that I can think of.

If you are on Enterprise Edition you can use [resource governor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895232.aspx) to set a maximum amount of memory that a particular workload group can consume which might help.

Comment: @MitchWheat - Yep, I added a first line because I'm not aware of any way of doing exactly what the OP asks for.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL 2008 you can use resource governor to achieve this. There you can set the request_max_memory_grant_percent to set the memory (this is the percent relative to the pool size specified by the pool's max_memory_percent value). This setting in not query specific, it is session specific.

Comment: not sure how that adds much to martin's (5 minute) older answer?

Comment: Sorry, but when I opened the window and didn't touched it foe few minutes - after saving that I saw the answer

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Martin's answer

If your queries are all the same or similar, working on the same data, then they will be sharing memory anyway.

Example:

A busy web site with 100 concurrent connections running 6 different parametrised queries between them on broadly the same range of data.

- 6 execution plans
- 100 user contexts
- one buffer pool with assorted flags and counters to show usage of each data page

If you have 100 different queries or they are not parametrised then *fix the code*.

Memory per query is something I've never thought or cared about since last millenium

Comment: I assumed the OP was talking about memory grants for operators like sorts and hash joins. Would be good to get some clarity as to the motivation for the question.